# Rails 4 cache_digests Not Catching Changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm attempting to use fragment caching with Rails 4 to cache my navigation menu.

**Model**

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Page', :touch => true

  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Page', 
    :foreign_key => 'parent_id'

  ...

end
```

This part is working fine. Whenever I update a nested page, all parents' `updated_at` values are changed. But a new cache view file for that group of pages is not written.

**Navigation View**

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <% Page.level_1.each do |page_1| %>
      <% cache page_1 do %>
      <li>
        <%= link_to page_1.title, level_1_page_path(page_1.slug) %>
        <% if page_1.children.count > 0 %>
          # continue nesting children
          ...
        <% end %>
      </li>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Why isn't Rails recognizing the change in the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had everything correct, but my model's scope:

```
scope :level_1, where(:level => 1)
```

was being cached by default, as it didn't contain `lambda`. Changing the scope to:

```
scope :level_1, -> { where(:level => 1) }
```

solved my problem and now cache digests work perfectly.